# C# Join string from object with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have an object that I have defined like this.

```cs
public class Model {
    public string id {get; set;}
    public string customer {get; set;}
    public string sentence {get; set;}
}
```

When working with my object I do it in collections which can have repeated elements by id and customer but different sentence, I need to iterate the common elements and join it's sentence like so:

| id | customer | sentence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | why |
| 1 | 001 | that |
| 2 | 002 | seperate |

I am trying to convert this to the following:

| id | customer | sentence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | why, that |
| 2 | 002 | seperate |

I currently have this code:

```cs
List<Model> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(json);
List<Model> result = data.GroupBy(x => new {
    x.id,
    x.customer
}).Select(x => new Model {
    id = x.Key.id,
    customer = x.Key.customer,
    sentence = String.Join(", ", x.Select(z => z.sentence)) // this is what I need to fix
}).ToList();
```

This however doesn't seem to work, what can I do to fix this. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The tables shown are the visual representation of a List, the first one would be the data variable and the last one how I want the result variable to be. The code doesn't work, it will still return the first visual representation.

My apologies for the unclear question.

Comment: x.Key.sentence.Select(z => z)

Comment: @Nonik this won't work

Comment: Finally, someone figured out what "doesn't seem to work" means in this post and upvoted. Could whoever did that [edit] the question to expand on "not working" and show compile/runtime errors and actual result if any?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The tables shown are the visual representation of a *List<Model>*, the first one would be the *data* variable and the last one how OP wants the *result* variable to be.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov my apologies. I just added Mike93041's description to the edit.

Comment: C# is a language of types: what is the type of `data.id` and `data.customer`?

Comment: @NetMage You mean data[i].id and data[i].customer? They're both strings as seen by the provided Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a code typo, the following works as you need:

```
List<Model> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(json);
List<Model> result = data.GroupBy(x => new {
    x.id,
    x.customer
}).Select(x => new Model {
    id = x.Key.id,
    customer = x.Key.customer,
    sentence = string.Join(", ", x.Select(z => z.sentence))
}).ToList();
```

Output:

```
1|001|why, that
2|002|seperate
```

Comment: can you show  even one difference between your  and OP query pls?

Comment: He was creating the GroupBy query without the new keyword which is needed in multi-key agroupations. *I don't know why it wasn't throwing an IDE error for him*

Comment: Compiller will show an error  immediately

Comment: @Serge Exactly, it throws

Comment: Hey, my bad. In my actual code I already had the new keyword in the GroupBy lambda. This code won't work for me. I keep ending up with the first visual representation.

Comment: @DannyVerdel I've replicated your case and It's working. Please have a look at [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F4Kdsh) code